# How I can Add subfolders

Tags: python

I need to make a directory structure. If it is, do not create if it is not created. I can create the main catalog, I can not add to this sub-directories - folder2, folder3, how I can do this?

```
def createSubfolder(self):
    if not os.path.exists('fold'):
        os.makedirs('fold')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot add to this ..."? Are there any errors? Any restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.makedirs()` happily accepts paths – just be sure to use `exist_ok=True`.

```py
os.makedirs('this/tree/will/be/magically/created', exist_ok=True)
```